Short episodes that played between ads about aliens
It is about two little blue aliens, one bigger and short, while the other is tall and thinner. They had a huge coin in one episode and used it to try and get a gumball out of a gumball machine. All the shorts were about them trying to get gumballs from this massive gumball machine they had. It was set in a desert, in an abandoned house.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

What do you mean they played between ads? Why is that important to answering the question, was this on a device, or in a movie theater, or what?

@OrganicMarble Not sure this is what OP means, but here, on public TV channels, we have very short cartoons between ads (think 5-10 seconds per cartoon, occasionally a little longer, with some rare gems going over one minute). They feature recurring characters that are usually only shown between ads, not in any separate show.

@AlexanderKlauer Thanks! That sounds very likely and is completely unfamiliar to me.
